# How do I stop urxvt adding a '+' when the line wraps

Tags: terminal, urxvt

I've been experimenting with uxrvt recently as a potential replacement for gnome-terminal. One problem I'm having with it is inserting continuation characters when a line wraps around. This is a problem with long URL's (e.g. password reset keys) as the URL is broken up and an extra character included.

How can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: Is `TERM` set to `TERM=rxvt-unicode` ?  What window manager are you using - gnome?  i know xmonad has a `crlf off` option specifically related to copying from the terminal, but not sure if this is what's driving your problem or if there is a related fix in whatever WM you're using.

Comment: TERM is set to "screen" as I'm running a screen session inside. However without entering a screen session TERM=rxvt-unicode I get the same effect.

I'm running under Gnome, but using urxvt as it handles UTF-8 better than gnome-terminal does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't do this for me.

```
echo -n abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yza bcd efg hji; echo -n abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yza bcd efg hji; echo abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yza bcd efg hji
```

results in just simple wrapped output, with no "+". I checked my ~/.config/app-defaults/URxvt to see if I had given any special setting for this, but nothing looks relevant. And moving that aside and starting a new terminal gives me same behavior.

I do see + at the start of wrapped lines *in vim*. Similarly, a "@" at the end of wrapped lines *in less*. But I assume you're just talking about wrapped lines at the shell prompt.

Do you still see this is you temporarily move aside all your .bashrc-and-friends files and start a new terminal?

Comment: Your right, that doesn't trigger it. I suspect I've blamed the wrong program as it's something I only really see with long URLs in my mail client.

Comment: Then if it's fixable it's probably a setting on your mail client or the pager it uses. If you're using mutt, I recommend you check out urlview. Once it's installed and you add a mutt keybinding for it, when you're looking a message you hit a key and see a list of all the urls in the mesage. Choose one, and it'll start in the browser you've specified.

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* it's urxvt that's adding the "+" signs?
I'm taking a wild guess here, and gonna assume you use mutt (because I use urxvt and had that issue with mutt).

Add `set markers = no` to your `muttrc.`

Comment: Blast from the past ;-) - yep I had added the change to muttrc in Nov 2010.

Comment: I'm glad you haven't been suffering from this for four years. I left this answer in great part for posterity's sake, since this result comes up pretty easily.